# How to compile srlua?

Tags: lua

I made a program today, and I was wondering on how exactly to make it an executable. I've researched and I've came up with using srlua. I've asked this previously, but I usually mess up on the same instruction. I was told to 'compile srlua' While I know exactly what to do right after I compile srlua, I don't know how to compile them right now.

I've gone through a few YouTube tutorials, and I managed to find one but only in Spanish. I was able to slightly follow along until he downloaded a precompiled version of srlua, where the download link is no longer there at the same page he was at.

Would anyone be able to explain what they're trying to say?

Comment: What platform? Have you read the README in the srlua tarball?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking, especially regarding the video you are asking about (and never linked to). And I'm not saying to actually link to a video -  nobody should have to go watch a video to explain it to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell CMake where the Lua files it needs are.

For me, the Lua includes are in `/usr/include/luaX.X`, where X.X is your version number, e.g. 5.3. The Lua libraries may be in `/usr/lib` (with filenames like `libluaX.X.so`).

If the locations differ for you, you can try `find / | grep "lua.h"` and `find / | grep "liblua"`.

Once you've located the folder which `lua.h` is in, and the appropriate library file like `liblua5.3.so`, you need to add these to the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the srlua folder.
For example, using lua5.3, you might replace this line:

```
include_directories(${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

with this one:

```
include_directories(/usr/include/lua5.3)
```

And for the libraries, you might replace this:

```
target_link_libraries(glue ${LUA_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(srlua ${LUA_LIBRARIES})
```

with this:

```
target_link_libraries(glue /usr/lib/liblua5.3.so)
target_link_libraries(srlua /usr/lib/liblua5.3.so)
```

After this, run `cmake ./` in  the srlua folder, then run `make`. `srlua` should be built.

Note: you may also have to remove the line `find_package ( Lua REQUIRED )`, it was a false error for me (it only built when I removed that line).

Comment: Hi! How would I use CMake for srlua?

Comment: Follow the instructions in the answer. The part where you use cmake is `cmake ./` at the end. Before that is configuring it.